# How do I call this method? (very much a newbie who's having a difficult time with Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c

Here's my code... my problem is that I don't know how to call this (checkIfDatabaseExists) from AppDidFinishLaunching in my AppDelegate.m file.

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"

static SQLiteDB *sharedSQLiteDB = nil;  //  makes this a singleton class

@implementation SQLiteDB

@synthesize db, dbPath, databaseKey;


//--------------    check for database or create it    ----------------|
#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (SQLiteDB *) sharedSQLiteDB  {

    if(!sharedSQLiteDB)  {
        sharedSQLiteDB = [[SQLiteDB alloc] init];
        [sharedSQLiteDB checkIfDatabaseExists];  //  check to see if d/b exists
    }
    return sharedSQLiteDB;
}
```

Comment: Why call [sharedSQLiteDB checkIfDatabaseExists]; you don't seem to do anything with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app delegate file, import SQLiteDB.h then call

```
SQLiteDB *db = [SQLiteDB sharedSQLiteDB];
```

Is that what you meant?

You declared `sharedSQLiteDB` as a class method (that leading + sign), so you invoke that on the class (as above). Your call to checkIfDatabaseExists suggests that that is an instance method (declared with a -).

I would suggest naming your static SQLiteDB instance with a leading _ or something to distinguish it from  the method named sharedSQLiteDB. It's confusing otherwise.

Am I missing something or does this help?

Comment: Don't use _ to prefix your variable names, that's reserved for Apple to do

Comment: Thanks everybody... that really helped me to get going... I appreciate the help from everybody!

Answer (score 2):

You call a static message with `[ClassName messageName]`, so:

```
 SQLiteDB* sdb = [SQLiteDB sharedSQLiteDB];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
[[SQLiteDB sharedSQLiteDB] checkIfDatabaseExists];
```

`sharedSQLiteDB` is a class method that implements the Singleton design pattern. (or shared instance in Cocoa).
You can learn more about that here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

Basically this pattern assures that there is only one object of a certain class instantiated during runtime.